# Error in Function to add Google Fonts in WordPress Theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have the following function in my Wordpress themes functions file which should add google fonts to the theme. The problem is that i am getting the following error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in /home/***/wp-content/themes/sienna/functions.php on line 382
```

Anyone know how I can fix this please ?

Heres the function

```
// Add Google Fonts
    function sienna_fonts_url() {
        $fonts_url = '';
        $font_families = array();
        $font_families[] = 'Questrial';
        $font_families[] = 'Open Sans:400,600,700';
        $font_families[] = 'Playfair Display:400,700';

        $query_args = array(
        'family' =&gt; urlencode( implode( '|', $font_families ) ),
        'subset' =&gt; urlencode( 'latin,latin-ext' ),
        );

        $fonts_url = add_query_arg( $query_args, 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css' );
        }

        return esc_url_raw( $fonts_url );
    }
```

Many thanks,

Scott.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
function sienna_fonts_url() {
$fonts_url = '';
$font_families = array();
$font_families[] = 'Questrial';
$font_families[] = 'Open Sans:400,600,700';
$font_families[] = 'Playfair Display:400,700';
$query_args = array(
    'family' => urlencode( implode( '|', $font_families ) ),
    'subset' => urlencode( 'latin,latin-ext' ),
);
$fonts_url = add_query_arg( $query_args, 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css' );
return esc_url_raw( $fonts_url );
```

}

Comment: Thanks but now im getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/**/wp-content/themes/sienna/functions.php on line 390

Comment: Sorry ignore that. Seems to be working now. Thanyou so much.

Comment: I am however getting an error in my console now. [code]GET https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?0=family%3EQuestrial%3A400%2C600%7COpen+Sa…00%2C600%2C700%7CPlayfair+Display%3A400%2C700&1=subset%3Elatin%2Clatin-ext [/code]

Comment: could you paste the complete url using the markdown convention? 
I can't access it this way

Comment: 'GET https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?0=family%3EQuestrial%3A400%2C600%7COpen+Sa…00%2C600%2C700%7CPlayfair+Display%3A400%2C700&1=subset%3Elatin%2Clatin-ext '

Comment: arghhhh not sure how in here

Comment: [link](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?0=family%3EQuestrial%3A400%7COpen+Sans%3A400%2C600%2C700%7CPlayfair+Display%3A400%2C700&1=subset%3Elatin%2Clatin-ext)

Comment: fixed my answer, have a look :)

Comment: Thankyou very much :)